# Which loss function should I use for shape extraction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I need to build a neural network to recognize multiple specific shapes configuration (Squares, Triangles…) in an image and change the color of them as the output.

So, the neural network will have (for example) an image of 32x32x1 (Gray scale) as input, and 32x32x3 as output. My question is: what kind of lose function should I use to train my neural network. Because I read some articles to found out, and this is not a classification or regression problem (from what I understood), so I am bit lost since I am new into this.

- Considering I have a database with the output images corresponding to the input image that I can train the network on
- I am using Tensorflow for this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you don’t have Shapes associated with the image pairs, just the pairs:**
You can build a image denoising network(https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/24/denoising-autoencoders-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/) and use de-convolution to generated the coloured image.

Loss Function: You can use MSE loss function which would calculate loss by comparing each pixel in each channel of the output image from the network and the real image.

**If you have shape associated with each input image:**
Then you can build a simple Deep neural network classifier to predict the shape and then based on shape fill the colour value in the output image(which do can perform using cv2 library in python)